# How to use onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with javascript and html. I am calling a function "getdata()",I am able  getting the  data dynamiaclly but when i click on the data which comes from

another function need to invoke, but in this i am getting null value. I dont know where i went wrong with this function. but if i use a  tag with onchange event handler, when we changing data from select drop down then i can see onchange is invoking the another function

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/li - So technically value can be used...but only if you use ol and not ul

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of `<a>` tag and `value` attribute on `<li>`
The format of `<options>` should be `<option>`

To make that work My suggestion is do as

```
 onclick='getlist("+group[i].name)+"')
```

Now the error you are facing is because the `getlist` function is not sending the value of li

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `data` attributes for normal HTML tags such as `li`, f.ex:

```
html += "<li data-value='"+(group[i].name)+"' "+
        "onclick='getlist(this.getAttribute(\'data-value\'));'>"+
        "<a href='#'>"+ group[i].name+"</a>"+
        "</li>;
```

Answer (score 0):

use  onclick='getlist(this.value); in anchor tag insted of li tag

Comment: Except that value in an a tag is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue is that there is a z-index issue. The a tag is being clicked on an executed first. Are you using html5 by chance? What I might do if i were you is something like.

```
<a href="#" data-value="x" onclick="getlist(this.getAttribute('data-value'))"></a>
```

Also, is there any particular reason you are using inline JS?

Answer (score 0):

An `li` in the `ul` doesn't have a `value` attribute. I think this is a good approach (without inline event)

```
function getdata(){
    var html = "<ul id='getlist'>";
    for(var i=0;i<group.length;i++){
        if(group[i] !== null)
          html = html+"<li><a href='#'>"+ group[i].name+"</a></li>";
     }
     return html+"</ul>";
}
document.getElementById('getlist').onclick=getlist;
// Function getlist
function getlist(e)
{
    e=e || window.event;
    var el=e.target || e.srcElement;
    alert(el.innerHTML); // or what ever you want
    return false;
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsbin.com/aqekat/7/edit).

Comment: Actually the li does have a value attribute. http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/li - but it has to be an integer and can only be used with ol